# Create a function from a vector to another

Tags: r, function, vector

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(-2.0,-1.75,-1.50,-1.25,-1.00,-0.75,-0.50,-0.25,0.00,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00,1.25,1.50,1.75,2.00,2.25,2.50,2.75)
y <- c(37.0000,24.1602,15.06250,8.91016,5.00000,2.72266,1.56250,1.09766,1.00000,1.03516,1.06250,1.03516,1.00000,1.09766,1.56250,2.72266,5.00000,8.91016,15.06250,24.16016)
```

I am trying to create a function that given a number from vector x, it returns the corresponding y value(same index). For example, `func(-2.0)` should return `37.0000`.

Currently I have this super ugly function that I don't think is what I am supposed to do:

```
func1 <- function(x) {
  if (x==-2.0) {return (37.0000)}
  else if (x==-1.75){return (24.1602)}
  else if (x==-1.50){return (15.06250)}
  else if (x==-1.25){return (8.91016)}
  else if (x==-1.00){return (5.00000)}
  else if (x==-0.75){return (2.72266)}
  else if (x==-0.50){return (1.56250)}
  else if (x==-0.25){return (1.09766)}
  else if (x==0.00){return (1.00000)}
  else if (x==0.25){return (1.03516)}
  else if (x==0.50){return (1.06250)}
  else if (x==0.75){return (1.03516)}
  else if (x==1.00){return (1.00000)}
  else if (x==1.25){return (1.09766)}
  else if (x==1.50){return (1.56250)}
  else if (x==1.75){return (2.72266)}
  else if (x==2.00){return (5.00000)}
  else if (x==2.25){return (8.91016)}
  else if (x==2.50){return (15.06250)}
  else if (x==2.75){return (24.16016)}
  else {return (Inf)}
}
```

Comment: No need for a function, `y[ which(x == -2.0) ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exact matching:

```
foo = function(u) {res=y[pmatch(u,x)];ifelse(is.na(res), Inf, res)}
#> foo(-2)
#[1] 37
#> foo(-1.8)
#[1] Inf
#> foo(-4)
#[1] Inf
```

Not sure about what you need but beware you can use linear interpolation (you can put method as constant instead of linear):

```
foo = approxfun(x,y, yleft=Inf, yright=Inf)
#> foo(-2)
#[1] 37
#> foo(-1.8)
#[1] 26.72816
#> foo(-4)
#[1] Inf
```

In this last case, the value is not Inf in the boundary domain defined by `x`.

Comment: Add option to handle `else {return (Inf)}`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing an interpolation. The R function for interpolation is `approx()`.

```
approx(x, y, xout = -2)

$x
[1] -2

$y
[1] 37
```

In practise it's easier to create an interpolation function using `approxfun()`. Try this:

```
foo <- approxfun(x, y)
foo(-2)
[1] 37
```

---

You should probably avoid using an exact matching strategy using `==` or `match()`.  The reason is simple - if you use calculated values to find the index position, you could find that the match is inexact.

Compare:

```
y[ which(x == -2.0) ]
[1] 37

y[ which(x == -2.00000000001) ]
numeric(0)
```

Similarly:

```
y[match(-2.0, x)]
[1] 37

y[match(-2.0000000000001, x)]
[1] NA
```

Comment: approxfun was my proposal minutes ago ... it need yright and yleft options moreover to handle OP requirements ...and it's just an 'alternative solution' maybe the OP wants really Inf in the 'holes' of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Since x and y are the same length, put x as names of y

```
names(y)<-x
y

      -2    -1.75     -1.5    -1.25       -1    -0.75     -0.5    -0.25        0     0.25      0.5     0.75        1     1.25      1.5     1.75        2 
37.00000 24.16020 15.06250  8.91016  5.00000  2.72266  1.56250  1.09766  1.00000  1.03516  1.06250  1.03516  1.00000  1.09766  1.56250  2.72266  5.00000 
    2.25      2.5     2.75 
 8.91016 15.06250 24.16016
```

This way, you can call by the names, e.g.

```
y["-2"]

-2 
37

y["-1.75"]

-1.75 
24.1602
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a function for this, I suggest you just use:

```
y[x == -1.75]
```

x == -1.75 returns a boolean vector so it will pick the right value for y.

If you really want a function:

```
f <- function(x,y,xi){
return(y[x == xi])
}
```

Comment: `which()` is more efficient.